# Error about MariaDB when I am using Mysql, discord.py

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

I am trying to make a command for my bot, in which when I put !p {text}, the text is inserted into the database, I am using Mysql, and the bot turns on, but when I use the command it throws the following error.

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1
```

This is the cmd

```
@client.command()
async def p(ctx, *, nam: str = None):
    sql = 'INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (%s)'
    cursor.execute(sql, (nam))
    await ctx.send(f"inserted {nam}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this https://aiosqlite.omnilib.dev/en/stable/api.html

You should really be using asynchronous coding.

Here is an example:

```
    async with aiosqlite.connect('database_name') as db:
        print("Connection Opened")
        async with db.execute('SELECT object FROM object_table WHERE object_value = ?', (object_value)) as cursor:
            value = await cursor.fetchone()
            value = list(value)
            value = value[0]
        value += 1
        await db.execute("UPDATE object_table SET object = ? WHERE object_value = ?", (value, object_value))
        await db.commit()
    print("Connection Closed")
```